# How to read this json data?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

How to read this json data from server

```
{
"DS": {
    "LST": [


     {
                "OID": 1,
                "OCD": "1",
                "OPE": "AIRCEL",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/aircelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 2,
                "OCD": "3",
                "OPE": "AIRTEL",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/airtelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 22,
                "OCD": "BSR",
                "OPE": "BSNL SPL RECHARGE",
                "IPH": "",
                "MIL": 0,
                "MXL": 0
            },
            {
                "OID": 4,
                "OCD": "4",
                "OPE": "BSNL Topup",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/bsnlsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 6,
                "OCD": "5",
                "OPE": "DOCOMO",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/docomosm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 7,
                "OCD": "6",
                "OPE": "IDEA",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/ideasm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 8,
                "OCD": "7",
                "OPE": "MTS",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/mtssm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 5,
                "OCD": "8",
                "OPE": "RELAINCE",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/reliancesm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 3,
                "OCD": "9",
                "OPE": "VODAFONE",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/vodafonesm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            }
        ],
        "LST1": [
            {
                "OID": 10,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "AIRTEL DTH",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/airtelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 11,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "BIGTV",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/aircelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 12,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "DISH TV",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/dishtvsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 9,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "SUN DIRECT",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/sundirectsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 13,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "TATA SKY",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/tataskysm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 14,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "VIDEOCON DTH",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/videoconsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            }
        ]
}
}
```

For reading the above json type i used the method is given below

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<SpinnerMenuItems>>(){}.getType();
                    List<SpinnerMenuItems> selectedNetwork = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(result.getResult()), listType);
                    settingDropDown(selectedNetwork);
```

Actually my problem is to read the json array from the json object and the json array are viewed in a listview by using custom adapter. I don't know how to read this.

For reading the json object i used the following model class

```
public class SpinnerMenuItems {
    @SerializedName("LST")
    String zeroList;
    @SerializedName("LST1")
    String firstList;

    public String getZeroList() {
        return zeroList;
    }

    public void setZeroList(String zeroList) {
        this.zeroList = zeroList;
    }

    public String getFirstList() {
        return firstList;
    }

    public void setFirstList(String firstList) {
        this.firstList = firstList;
    }

}
```

The above model class is to read the list inside the json object.

The below model class is to read the json array which is placed inside the json object

```
public class ListZero {

    @SerializedName("IPH")
    String images;
    @SerializedName("OID")
    String oid;
    @SerializedName("OPE")
    String ope;
    @SerializedName("OCD")
    String ocd;
    @SerializedName("MIL")
    String mil;

    public String getMxl() {
        return mxl;
    }

    public void setMxl(String mxl) {
        this.mxl = mxl;
    }

    public String getMil() {
        return mil;
    }

    public void setMil(String mil) {
        this.mil = mil;
    }

    public String getOcd() {
        return ocd;
    }

    public void setOcd(String ocd) {
        this.ocd = ocd;
    }

    public String getOpe() {
        return ope;
    }

    public void setOpe(String ope) {
        this.ope = ope;
    }

    public String getOid() {
        return oid;
    }

    public void setOid(String oid) {
        this.oid = oid;
    }

    public String getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(String images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @SerializedName("MXL")
    String mxl;

}
```

Please help me how to read the json array which is placed inside the json object. In my case i need to read the only one json array list and view the list in a listview. How to read the json array.

Comment: Did you give a try to the answer I posted? it was helpful? does it solved the problem?

Comment: @ ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ  in your answer how can i get the json arraylist

Comment: using the getters... but that is another question... am interested about the json serialization, if that work please accept the answer

Comment: have you checked my updated answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: android  textview in  custom adater getting the single list  position in getview remaing text data are returning null in android

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

```
@SerializedName("LST")
String zeroList;
@SerializedName("LST1")
String firstList;
```

see your json..

[image]

you dont have there Strings but a list of Objects....

those  objects look almost like **ListZero** but you are missing the **MXL** attribute...

---

your pojo should look like

```
class SpinnerMenuItems {

    @SerializedName("LST")
    List<ListZero> zeroList;
    @SerializedName("LST1")
    List<ListZero> firstList;

    public List<ListZero> getZeroList() {
        return zeroList;
    }

    public void setZeroList(List<ListZero> zeroList) {
        this.zeroList = zeroList;
    }

    public List<ListZero> getFirstList() {
        return firstList;
    }

    public void setFirstList(List<ListZero> firstList) {
        this.firstList = firstList;
    }

}
```

and you need an extra class (the one with DS)

```
class DS {

    @SerializedName("DS")
    private SMI mSMI;

    public SMI getmSMI() {
        return mSMI;
    }

    public void setmSMI(SMI mSMI) {
        this.mSMI = mSMI;
    }
}
```

---

to test that place the json in a file and do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("./foo.json"));

    DS x = gson.fromJson(reader, DS.class);
    SMI mSMI = x.getmSMI();
    System.out.println(x.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please post your answer  briefly and explain how to read the json data and set to the listview

Comment: hold on! i need to import the gson lib

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArrayObj{
    private int OID;
    private String OCD;
    private String OPE;
    private String IPH;
    private int MIL;
    private int MXL;
    ...
    add the getters and setters
}
```

---

```
public class LSTObject{
    private List<ArrayObj> LST;
    ...
    add the getters and setters
}
```

---

```
public class FinalJSON{
    private LSTObject DS;
    ...
    add the setters and getters
}
```

---

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
FinalJSON finalJSON = gson.fromJson(jsonStr,FinalJSON.class);
```

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();
FinalJSON finalJSON = gson.fromJson(jsonStr,FinalJSON.class);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ tool to parse your Json data easily.

In your case it should be like this.

com.example.DS.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class DS {

@SerializedName("LST")
@Expose
private List<LST> lST = null;
@SerializedName("LST1")
@Expose
private List<LST1> lST1 = null;

public List<LST> getLST() {
return lST;
}

public void setLST(List<LST> lST) {
this.lST = lST;
}

public List<LST1> getLST1() {
return lST1;
}

public void setLST1(List<LST1> lST1) {
this.lST1 = lST1;
}

}
```

com.example.Example.java

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("DS")
@Expose
private DS dS;

public DS getDS() {
return dS;
}

public void setDS(DS dS) {
this.dS = dS;
}

}
```

com.example.LST.java

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class LST {

@SerializedName("OID")
@Expose
private Integer oID;
@SerializedName("OCD")
@Expose
private String oCD;
@SerializedName("OPE")
@Expose
private String oPE;
@SerializedName("IPH")
@Expose
private String iPH;
@SerializedName("MIL")
@Expose
private Integer mIL;
@SerializedName("MXL")
@Expose
private Integer mXL;

public Integer getOID() {
return oID;
}

public void setOID(Integer oID) {
this.oID = oID;
}

public String getOCD() {
return oCD;
}

public void setOCD(String oCD) {
this.oCD = oCD;
}

public String getOPE() {
return oPE;
}

public void setOPE(String oPE) {
this.oPE = oPE;
}

public String getIPH() {
return iPH;
}

public void setIPH(String iPH) {
this.iPH = iPH;
}

public Integer getMIL() {
return mIL;
}

public void setMIL(Integer mIL) {
this.mIL = mIL;
}

public Integer getMXL() {
return mXL;
}

public void setMXL(Integer mXL) {
this.mXL = mXL;
}

}
```

com.example.LST1.java

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class LST1 {

@SerializedName("OID")
@Expose
private Integer oID;
@SerializedName("OCD")
@Expose
private String oCD;
@SerializedName("OPE")
@Expose
private String oPE;
@SerializedName("IPH")
@Expose
private String iPH;
@SerializedName("MIL")
@Expose
private Integer mIL;
@SerializedName("MXL")
@Expose
private Integer mXL;

public Integer getOID() {
return oID;
}

public void setOID(Integer oID) {
this.oID = oID;
}

public String getOCD() {
return oCD;
}

public void setOCD(String oCD) {
this.oCD = oCD;
}

public String getOPE() {
return oPE;
}

public void setOPE(String oPE) {
this.oPE = oPE;
}

public String getIPH() {
return iPH;
}

public void setIPH(String iPH) {
this.iPH = iPH;
}

public Integer getMIL() {
return mIL;
}

public void setMIL(Integer mIL) {
this.mIL = mIL;
}

public Integer getMXL() {
return mXL;
}

public void setMXL(Integer mXL) {
this.mXL = mXL;
}

}
```

After this Parse json to custom model using Gson

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Example yourModelClass = gson.fromJson(yourJsonResponse, Example.class);
```

from there you can access anything which ever you want from the model. like

```
DS myDSObject = yourModelClass.getDS();
List<LST> lST = myDSObject.getLST();

LST myLSTObject = lST.get(0) // 1st Item.
```

Then here inside array data you can get like

```
 String oID= myLSTObject.getOID();
 String oCD=   myLSTObject.getOCD();
 String oPE=   myLSTObject.getOPE();
```

...... in similar way you can get the rest data

Comment: Please tell me how to get the json array to view in listview

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Data {

    @SerializedName("OID")
    String oid;
    @SerializedName("OCD")
    String ocd;
    @SerializedName("OPE")
    String ope;
    @SerializedName("IPH")
    String ocd;
    @SerializedName("MIL")
    String mil;
    @SerializedName("MXL")
    String mxl;

    // generate getter/setters
    ...

}

public class DS {

@SerializedName("LST")
private List<Data> lstObject;

@SerializedName("LST1")
private List<Data> lst1Object;

// generate getter/setters
...
}

//parsing code.

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            List<Data> lstList = new ArrayList<>(); // LST
            List<Data> lst1List = new ArrayList<>();  /// LST1
            DS ds = new DS();

            JSONObject rootObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("DS");
            JSONArray lstArray = rootObj.getJSONArray("LST");
            JSONArray lst1Array = rootObj.getJSONArray("LST1");

            for(int i=0; i<lstArray.length; i++) {
               JSONObject obj = lstArray.getJSONObject(i);
               Data data = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), Data.class);
               lstList.add(data);
            }

            for(int i=0; i<lst1Array.length; i++) {
               JSONObject obj = lst1Array.getJSONObject(i);
               Data data = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), Data.class);
               lst1List.add(data);
            }

            ds.setLST(lstList);
            ds.setLST1(lst1List);
```