# How to read the json array from json object?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I am facing the issue in reading the json array from the json object

```
    { "DS": {
        "LST": [
            {
                "OID": 1,
                "OCD": "1",
                "OPE": "AIRCEL",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/aircelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 2,
                "OCD": "3",
                "OPE": "AIRTEL",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/airtelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 22,
                "OCD": "BSR",
                "OPE": "BSNL SPL RECHARGE",
                "IPH": "",
                "MIL": 0,
                "MXL": 0
            },
            {
                "OID": 4,
                "OCD": "4",
                "OPE": "BSNL Topup",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/bsnlsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 6,
                "OCD": "5",
                "OPE": "DOCOMO",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/docomosm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 7,
                "OCD": "6",
                "OPE": "IDEA",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/ideasm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 8,
                "OCD": "7",
                "OPE": "MTS",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/mtssm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 5,
                "OCD": "8",
                "OPE": "RELAINCE",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/reliancesm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 3,
                "OCD": "9",
                "OPE": "VODAFONE",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/vodafonesm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            }
        ],
        "LST1": [
            {
                "OID": 10,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "AIRTEL DTH",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/airtelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 11,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "BIGTV",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/aircelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 12,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "DISH TV",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/dishtvsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 9,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "SUN DIRECT",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/sundirectsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 13,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "TATA SKY",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/tataskysm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 14,
                "OCD": "0",
                "OPE": "VIDEOCON DTH",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/videoconsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            }
        ]
}
}
```

The above json data is from server and how to read the json array in that .

My model class for reading json data are

```
public class SpinnerRootObject {
    @SerializedName("DS")
    SpinnerMenuItems ds;
    public SpinnerMenuItems getDs() {
        return ds;
    }

    public void setDs(SpinnerMenuItems ds) {
        this.ds = ds;
    }
}

public class SpinnerMenuItems 
{
    @SerializedName("LST")
    ListZero zeroList;
    @SerializedName("LST1")
    String firstList;

    public  ListZero getZeroList() {
        return zeroList;
    }

    public void setZeroList( ListZero zeroList) {
        this.zeroList = zeroList;
    }

    public String getFirstList() {
        return firstList;
    }

    public void setFirstList(String firstList) {
        this.firstList = firstList;
    }
}

public class ListZero {

    @SerializedName("IPH")
    String images;
    @SerializedName("OID")
    String oid;
    @SerializedName("OPE")
    String ope;
    @SerializedName("OCD")
    String ocd;
    @SerializedName("MIL")
    String mil;
    @SerializedName("MXL")
    String mxl;

    public String getMxl() {
        return mxl;
    }

    public void setMxl(String mxl) {
        this.mxl = mxl;
    }

    public String getMil() {
        return mil;
    }

    public void setMil(String mil) {
        this.mil = mil;
    }

    public String getOcd() {
        return ocd;
    }

    public void setOcd(String ocd) {
        this.ocd = ocd;
    }

    public String getOpe() {
        return ope;
    }

    public void setOpe(String ope) {
        this.ope = ope;
    }

    public String getOid() {
        return oid;
    }

    public void setOid(String oid) {
        this.oid = oid;
    }

    public String getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(String images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
}
```

The above code are model class for reading json.

The code used for reading the json from server is

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
                    SpinnerRootObject spinnerRootObject = gson.fromJson(result.getResult(), SpinnerRootObject.class);
                    settingDropDown((List<SpinnerRootObject>) spinnerRootObject);
```

While using the above method the exception is occurred
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 15 path . i don't know how to read the json array in given json data

I need to pass the json arraylist data into the custom adapter

```
 public void settingDropDown( List<SpinnerRootObject> selectedNetwork)
 {
     customAdapter = new Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter
           (getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items,R.id.serviceName,selectedNetwork);
     selectMenu.setAdapter(customAdapter);
 }
```

Please help me how to get the json array from the json object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read this json data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710207/how-to-read-this-json-data)

Comment: You never told us what you want to do with the JSON data, but I would recommend just using simpleJSON.

Comment: https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-asynctask-json-parsing-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Some of data are in integer , so need to change this class

```
 public class ListZero {

    @SerializedName("IPH")
    String images;
    @SerializedName("OID")
    int oid;      // do this integer
    @SerializedName("OPE")
    String ope;
    @SerializedName("OCD")
    String ocd;
    @SerializedName("MIL")
    int mil;  // do this integer
    @SerializedName("MXL")
    int mxl;  // do this integer

    //getter setter ... do modify getter and setter of oid,mil and mxl accordingly..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
 import java.util.List;
 import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


  public class SpinnerRootObject {

        @SerializedName("DS")
        @Expose
        private DS dS;

        public DS getDS() {
            return dS;
        }

        public void setDS(DS dS) {
            this.dS = dS;
        }


        public class DS {

            @SerializedName("LST")
            @Expose
            private List<LST> lST = null;
            @SerializedName("LST1")
            @Expose
            private List<LST1> lST1 = null;

            public List<LST> getLST() {
                return lST;
            }

            public void setLST(List<LST> lST) {
                this.lST = lST;
            }

            public List<LST1> getLST1() {
                return lST1;
            }

            public void setLST1(List<LST1> lST1) {
                this.lST1 = lST1;
            }

        }

        public class LST1 {

            @SerializedName("OID")
            @Expose
            private Integer oID;
            @SerializedName("OCD")
            @Expose
            private String oCD;
            @SerializedName("OPE")
            @Expose
            private String oPE;
            @SerializedName("IPH")
            @Expose
            private String iPH;
            @SerializedName("MIL")
            @Expose
            private Integer mIL;
            @SerializedName("MXL")
            @Expose
            private Integer mXL;

            public Integer getOID() {
                return oID;
            }

            public void setOID(Integer oID) {
                this.oID = oID;
            }

            public String getOCD() {
                return oCD;
            }

            public void setOCD(String oCD) {
                this.oCD = oCD;
            }

            public String getOPE() {
                return oPE;
            }

            public void setOPE(String oPE) {
                this.oPE = oPE;
            }

            public String getIPH() {
                return iPH;
            }

            public void setIPH(String iPH) {
                this.iPH = iPH;
            }

            public Integer getMIL() {
                return mIL;
            }

            public void setMIL(Integer mIL) {
                this.mIL = mIL;
            }

            public Integer getMXL() {
                return mXL;
            }

            public void setMXL(Integer mXL) {
                this.mXL = mXL;
            }

        }






        public class LST {

            @SerializedName("OID")
            @Expose
            private Integer oID;
            @SerializedName("OCD")
            @Expose
            private String oCD;
            @SerializedName("OPE")
            @Expose
            private String oPE;
            @SerializedName("IPH")
            @Expose
            private String iPH;
            @SerializedName("MIL")
            @Expose
            private Integer mIL;
            @SerializedName("MXL")
            @Expose
            private Integer mXL;

            public Integer getOID() {
                return oID;
            }

            public void setOID(Integer oID) {
                this.oID = oID;
            }

            public String getOCD() {
                return oCD;
            }

            public void setOCD(String oCD) {
                this.oCD = oCD;
            }

            public String getOPE() {
                return oPE;
            }

            public void setOPE(String oPE) {
                this.oPE = oPE;
            }

            public String getIPH() {
                return iPH;
            }

            public void setIPH(String iPH) {
                this.iPH = iPH;
            }

            public Integer getMIL() {
                return mIL;
            }

            public void setMIL(Integer mIL) {
                this.mIL = mIL;
            }

            public Integer getMXL() {
                return mXL;
            }

            public void setMXL(Integer mXL) {
                this.mXL = mXL;
            }

        }



    }

Try this model class.
```